# Allocating elements from a smaller matrix to a bigger one by user input

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 3 smaller matrices (in multidimensional arrays), all of them 4x4. I want to build a bigger matrix (8x8) for each smaller one, but rearranging the position of each element of the smaller matrix into a new position in the bigger one, according to user matrix input:

For example, I have those 3 little matrices:

```
A=repmat(1, [4 4]);
B=repmat(2, [4 4]);
C=repmat(3, [4 4]);
```

and the bigger one `K=zeros(8);`. The user input matrix is this one:

```
user=[1 2 7 8; 3 4 1 2; 3 4 7 8];
```

So the first bigger matrix must have a configuration where:

[image]

The red numbers are the new row and columns in the bigger matrix, resulting in this for `K`:

[image]

How  can I insert values from the smaller matrices to the bigger matrix in this way?

Comment: What should be done with the second and third rows of `user`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you need this, but this is the solution I thought.

```
K = zeros(8,8);
for ii=1:4
    for jj=1:4
       K(user(1,ii),user(1,jj)) = A(ii,jj);
       K(user(2,ii),user(2,jj)) = B(ii,jj);
       K(user(3,ii),user(3,jj)) = C(ii,jj);
    end
end
```

Comment: Its for a math method that I have to adapt. Is there a way to make it iterative? your code works, but I wanna know if can be adapted for n matrices, not just 3.

Comment: The code can be generalized, store the `N` matrices A,B,C, etc.. in a 3D matrix (`cube`) and with another for loop over the third dimension (`z=1...N`). the inner lines can be replaced with `K(user(1,ii),user(1,jj)) = cube(ii,jj,z)`. Not sure about the performances with 3 nested for loops but there are not enough information for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using a row of `user` as the row and column indices into `K`, like so:

```
K(user(1, :), user(1, :)) = A;
```

If you want to iterate over each smaller matrix and user input, inserting them all into the same larger matrix `K`, I'd first put the smaller matrices into a single [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), then simply repeat the above in a [for loop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html):

```
smallMats = {A, B, C};
K = zeros(8);
for row = 1:size(user, 1)
  K(user(row, :), user(row, :)) = smallMats{row};
end
```

This can easily be extended to more matrices by adding to `user` and `smallMats`.